# How to split a csv file 20 lines at a time using Splitter EIP, in apache camel?

Tags: java, apache, csv, apache-camel, splitter

I have a **csv file** having 2000 lines. I wish to **split it 20 lines** at a time and send each to a processor in apache camel. How do I do it using **Splitter EIP** ? Please help ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to spend some time to research the Apache Camel documentation. For example on the Splitter EIP page its all documented how you can do this.

See https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/eips/split-eip.html#_splitting_files_by_grouping_n_lines_together at the section *Splitting files by grouping N lines together*

Comment: Thanks. I will consider doing it.

Answer (score 1):

```
package com.camel;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.csv.CsvDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.QuoteMode;

public class FileSplitter {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        CsvDataFormat csvParser = new CsvDataFormat(CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
        csvParser.setSkipHeaderRecord(true);
        csvParser.setQuoteMode(QuoteMode.ALL);
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {
                String fileName = "Hello.csv";
                int lineCount = 20;
                System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);
                System.out.println("lineCount = " + lineCount);
                from("file:data/inbox?noop=true&fileName=" + fileName).unmarshal(csvParser).split(body()).streaming()
                        .aggregate(constant(true), new ArrayListAggregationStrategy()).completionSize(lineCount)
                        .completionTimeout(1500).marshal(csvParser)
                        .to("file:data/outbox?fileName=${file:name.noext}_${header.CamelSplitIndex}.csv");
            }
        });
        context.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        context.stop();
        System.out.println("End");
    }
}
```